# Array in another Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, vector, int

I was creating code in C# but i can't create an array in another one.

```
int[, , ,] linee = new int[4, 4, 4, 4];


int[] line1 = new int[] { 10, 50, 150, 50 };
int[] line2 = new int[] { 10, 50, 10, 100 };
int[] line3 = new int[] { 10, 100, 150, 100 };
int[] line4 = new int[] { 150, 50, 150, 100 };

linee[0] = line1;
```

It gives me error:

> Error CS0022 The number of indexes in [] is incorrect.

(in the last line)

Comment: **What** error do you get? We canot guess, or at least we don´t want to.

Comment: Error CS0022 The number of indexes in [] is incorrect.

(in the last line)

Comment: Are you searching for [`jagged arrays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)?

Comment: i want a multi dimensional array which in each dimension there are an array

Comment: Well yea? `int[][][]`

Comment: Did you consult **[Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)** and **[Jagged Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)** in the documentation?

Comment: It really would help if you showed us what you will be using this array for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multidimensional arrays in C# you need something like this

```
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                             { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing [multi-dimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) with [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) or an array of arrays.

You are declaring a multi-dimensional array but then you are trying to assign as if it were a jagged array.

For a multi-dimensional array you need assign the values individually like this:

```
int[,,,] linee = new int[4, 4, 4, 4];

linee[0, 0, 0, 0] = 10;
linee[0, 0, 0, 1] = 50;
linee[0, 0, 0, 2] = 150;
linee[0, 0, 0, 3] = 50;
```

For a jagged array you can assign an existing array the way you are trying to do:

```
int[][][][] jaggedArray = new int[4][][][];

int[] line1 = new int[] { 10, 50, 150, 50 };
jaggedArray[0][0][0] = line1;
```